# useEffect not updating on auth.currentUser change

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, use-effect

I want to update my state whenever the user authentication state changes (in my navigation page):

```
import {auth} from '../firebase.js' // where auth is initialized with getAuth() from firebase/auth
const Navigation = () => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("Here"); // Gets logged on sign out but not on sign in
        setIsAuthenticated(Boolean(auth.currentUser));
    }, [auth.currentUser])
    return ({isAuthenticated ? <SomeComponent /> : <SomeComponent />})
}
```

**firebase.js**

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
export {auth}
```

Then in my login component I have the signing function which should be and is updating the value of auth.currentUser:

```
const signIn = ({ email, password }) => {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(auth.currentUser); // This is working, meaning auth.currentUser value has changed
      })
      .catch((err) => setFirebaseError(err));
};
```

This works and gets executed whenever I sign out, but doesn't execute when a user signs in and I can't figure out why.

I know that the auth.currentUser variable is being updated since I print it out in the sign in function, but for some reason the useEffect does not recognize this and does not fire?

Comment: Can you show us some more code. What you've shown is just not enough for us to even hazard a guess as to what might be going wrong at your end.

Comment: The best suggestion I'd give is to add a console log within your useEffect and see if it actually rerenders when needed. The useEffect surely will change if `auth.currentUser` is either a props or a state, so it's more likely that you get the rerender but with no effects when setIsAuthenticated is set on true

Comment: I've added some more code, hopefully this clarifies my problem. @ale917k I have tried logging within the useEffect and have noticed that it gets executed on sign out but not on sign in which I found very strange

Comment: I think the problem might be that I am importing auth and so it is not a prop or a state, is this a problem. Will changes in imported variables not initiate a re-render? I have included how I have initialized auth

Comment: Try setting [auth] in your useEffect dep array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `auth.currentUser` won't work because it's more or less a global variable exposed by firebase which will not trigger any sort of an update in react.

What you should rather do is subscribe to on `onAuthStateChanged` which will trigger whenever user logs in or out, and then use that to toggle your `isAuthenticated` flag.

For firebase v9

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const auth = getAuth();

  const listener = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(!!user);
  });

  return () => {
    listener();
  };
}, []);
```

For firebase v8

```
import { useState } from "react";
import firebase from "firebase";

const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const listener = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(!!user);
  });

  return () => {
    listener();
  };
}, []);
```

Or even better, you can check out [react-firebase-hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks) or [reactfire](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/reactfire) which provide a pretty nice set of hooks on top of firebase JS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would like to clarify in the case of switching directly between different users. You can force React to always render on user change by wrapping it in a Proxy. This will make sure React is happy and that you can still access all the methods directly. Use it like so:

```
const {user} = useAuth(); // at component level
...
  user.linkWithPopup(...) // call whatever method you like in some effect
```

```
// invoke this from anywhere inside your app
export default function useAuth() {
  const error = useSelector(state => state.useAuth.error);
  const user = useSelector(state => state.useAuth.user);

  return useMemo(() => ({error, user}), [error, user]);
}
```

```
// invoke this just after your top level providers
export function useAuthSingleton() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function setUserAsync(user) {
      try {
        if (user) {
          setError(null);

          function get (target, prop, receiver) {
            const origValue = Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
            if (typeof origValue === 'function') return origValue.bind(target);
            return origValue;
          }

          return setUser(new Proxy(user, {get}));
        }
        
        if (isSignInWithEmailLink(auth, window.location.href)) return;
        const credential = await signInAnonymously(auth);
        if (!credential?.user) throw new Error('No user found');  
      } catch (error) {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.error(errorCode, errorMessage);
      }
    }

    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, setUserAsync);
    return () => unsubscribe(); // not that it matters for a singleton
  }, []);

  // grab a copy of dispatch from wherever you like first
  useEffect(() => {dispatch({type: types.ERROR, error});}, [error]);
  useEffect(() => {dispatch({type: types.USER, user});}, [user]);
}
```